# Преобразование error объекта в json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Использую express, возникла проблема.

При возникновении ошибки во время запроса на сервер, он должен вернуть обьект ошибки.

Как было раньше:

```
export async function getProjectsList(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json(err);
    }
}
```

Но Response.json() вызывает для переданного объекта JSON.stringify()

```js
const error = new Error('Just an error!');
console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
```

Сейчас создал функцию:

```js
const error = new Error('Just an error!');

const errPreJson = err => ({error: err.name, message: err.message});

console.log(JSON.stringify(errPreJson(error)));
```

Но везде так использовать желания особо нет, когда можно делать так:

```js
const error = new Error('Just an error!');
console.log(JSON.stringify(error, ['name', 'message']));
```

Как бы организовать такое поведение без создания дополнительных функций, ну и чтобы только для инстансов Error работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const oldJsonStringify = JSON.stringify;
JSON.stringify = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Error)
    obj = { error: obj.name, message: obj.message };
  return oldJsonStringify(obj);
};

console.log(JSON.stringify({a:1}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('Just an error!')));
```